# Understand Clojure binding syntax

Tags: clojure, binding, jvm

I am learning Clojure and was reading about `doseq` when I noticed an example like below on the [official Clojure doc](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/doseq) for `doseq`

```
(doseq [x [-1 0 1]
        y [1  2 3]] 
  (prn (* x y)))
```

My confusion is with the expression `[x [-1 0 1] y [1 2 3]]`.

Does this signify a **binding expression**? I tried some amount of google search but could not come across any documentation that describes such a form.

Could someone help me with understanding the various syntax representations for binding forms in Clojure?

Comment: clojuredocs.org is not in any way an official source of clojure documentation. It is user-contributed examples of varying quality. The only official thing on that page is `doseq`'s docstring, which tells you to read the docstring of `for` to learn how it works. I agree it would be better if `doseq` had its own thorough documentation, but at least it points you to the right thing to read.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a "[binding form"](https://clojure.org/reference/special_forms#binding-forms) in that it "binds" the values from the expression to the name `x` in turn. So it colloquially means an expression that binds names to values. This is part of "destructuring binding forms" which bind names to parts of a compound value such as a list or map.

The term "binding" instead of "setting" helps convey the difference between what this is doing and setting variables in some other programming languages. The name is attached to the value for the time it takes for the form inside the `doseq` to run, then the name is released to be attached to another value.

Clojure offers arbitrary structural binding to give names to any part of a value in most places in the language that assign names (bind symbols)

```
(doseq [[x1 x2] [[-1 -1] [0 0] [1 1]]
        y [1  2 3]] 
  (prn (* x1 x2 y)))
```

is also a binding expression though it looks slightly deeper into the data and assigns names to two values per item in the first vector (and assumes there are two numbers in each of them) I'm very fond of [this tutorial on destructuring/binding](http://blog.jayfields.com/2010/07/clojure-destructuring.html)

Comment: true, I'll change it to sequence of sequences with at least two numbers"

Comment: Thanks for this detailed explanation. It helps!

Answer (score 2):

It is like a nested for loop in Java. You can also do the nesting "manually":

```
(dotest
  (newline)
  (println "version 1")
  (doseq [x [1 2]
          y [:a :b :c]]
    (println  x y))

  (newline)
  (println "version 2")
  (doseq [x [1 2]]
    (doseq [y [:a :b :c]]
      (println x y))))

with results:
version 1
1 :a
1 :b
1 :c
2 :a
2 :b
2 :c

version 2
1 :a
1 :b
1 :c
2 :a
2 :b
2 :c
```

Note that `doseq` always returns `nil`, and is only good for generating side-effects (like printing to the screen).

A `for` expression behaves similarly, but returns a (lazy) sequence of values (note we are generating a vector `[x y]` on each loop):

```
(newline)
(println "For generates a (lazy) sequence:"
  (for [x [1 2]
        y [:a :b :c]]
    [x y]))
```

with result:

```
For generates a (lazy) sequence: ([1 :a] [1 :b] [1 :c] [2 :a] [2 :b] [2 :c])
```

Comment: +1 for depicting alternate forms. However, the post does not really answer my question. I am currently more concerned with the clojure binding syntax than alternate forms since I am learning the language and uncerstanding the syntax at this stage is my priority.